# How to get specific file's directory name without full path in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, path

Node.js official docs provide this example:

```js
path.dirname('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux');
// Returns: '/foo/bar/baz/asdf'
```

However, I actually want `'asdf'` instead of full path `'/foo/bar/baz/asdf'`.

Despite some string manipulation, what is the best way, or is there any official API I can directly get that piece of string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [path.basename()](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path) on the directory path returned by path.dirname() as shown below. This method returns the last part of the given path.

```
const path = require('path');
const dirPath = path.dirname('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux');
console.log(path.basename(dirPath))
```

Answer (score 1):

Offical API or module will also do a string manipulation, it's pretty simple :

```
path.dirname('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux').split("/").pop(); // asdf
```

For all plateform :

```
 path.dirname('/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux').split(/\/|\\/).pop(); // asdf
```

Comment: I think it is better to use `path.basename()` as your solution won't catch platform specific differences in the presentation of file paths. For example, your code may fail on Windows as the path separator is `\\` on this platform.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this simple line of code should give you the desired result.

```
path.basename(path.dirname(''/foo/bar/baz/asdf/quux''))
```